# View Derived Types option missing in Object Browser Settings

Tags: visual-studio-2010

This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh81x5te.aspx) about how to display inheritance graphs in Visual Studio 2010 says there should be an "Show Derived Types" option in the Object Browser Settings and the Class View Settings. However, the option shows up in neither location in my copy of Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Ultimate. Does anybody know why and how to resolve it?

**Edit**
[image]
The original link is broken. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh81x5te(v=vs.90).aspx) is a link to the same article but for Visual Studio 2008 instead of 2010 (perhaps Microsoft removed the article for 2010 given that it doesn't work).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is caused by the object browsing scope I selected in the Browse box. If I select Custom Component Set in the Browser box, I cannot find the “Show Derived Types” in the Object Browser Settings. But if I select the .NET Framework 4 , I can find the “Show Derived Types” in the Object Browser Settings. Which leaves me with the question of how do I see derived types for classes in my project?

Update: I've used [Telerik JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) (a free tool) to find derived types. However, since upgrading to Visual Studio 2015 (problem still exists) I've been using the `Find All References` (Shift + F12) on class constructors to help find derived types. This works well for abstract classes as calls only come from derived types, and a little more messy for non abstract classes (depending on usage).

Answer (score 0):

<sub>*This is not really an answer, as I cannot resolve the problem, but it allows me to include an image.*</sub>

I can see derived types for mscorlib 2.0 but not mscorlib 4.0 (VS2015) when I set the scope to "All Components"; however, I can see them when I set the scope to ".NET Framework 4.0". This confirms Ɖiamond ǤeezeƦ statement that the issue is caused by the object browsing scope.

[image]

Comment: And if a comment won't work due to formatting/image stuff, then it's customary to add the answer as a community wiki, to make it clear that you have no intention of gaining reputation from the act.